# Where to find snap packages published by official software project maintainers?

Tags: package-management, snap

I want to use snap and docker more often for my next Xubuntu install.

Currently I often use `sources.list.d` and link the repo from the software project website.

Is there a `snap` command that shows snap packages published by the official software project team? For example, are these snap packages tagged in some way?

Comment: What is "the official software project team"? Which project? Xubuntu? Ubuntu? Docker?

Comment: for example, for the postgresql package, the postgresql project team.

Answer (score 4):

Snaps are created directly by the software vendor. This is in contrast to deb packages, where a Debian or Ubuntu developer acts as an intermediary, packaging the upstream software and releasing it for the distribution.

Provided you have [snapd installed](http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/install), you can find available apps by running `snap find`. You can also browse available apps at [uappexplorer.com](https://uappexplorer.com/apps?type=snappy).

Comment: thx. the website is what i was searching for.

Comment: @554c46 would u please set it as accepted answer, so other users find the solution easily.

Answer (score 3):

I use `snap info` to see the who the publisher is, for example `snap info docker`:

```
name:      docker
summary:   "The docker app deployment mechanism"
publisher: docker-inc
description: |
  Docker for snappy.
```

You can also see it when doing a search; `snap find docker`:

```
docker  1.11.2-9  docker-inc  -      The docker app deployment mechanism
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps with your question.

First you need to know how the official developer, PUBLISHER, as it is properly called in the Snap repositories, is called.

An example, we are looking for a snap for docker, we want to install docker using snap.

So the official exact name of Docker, as publisher, in the snap repos is "docker-inc".

If we search with

```
$ snap find docker
```

several results will appear,

```
me@me-MyComputer:~$ snap find docker
Name             Version     Publisher              Notes    Summary
docker           18.06.1-ce  docker-inc             -        The docker app deployment mechanism
img              0.4.6       bashfulrobot           -        Unprivileged Dockerfile & OCI compatible container img builder.
dry              0.9-beta.5  monch0                 -        A Docker manager for the terminal
kata-containers  1.3.1       katacontainers         classic  Lightweight virtual machines that seamlessly plug into the containers ecosystem
kube-proxy       1.12.2      canonical              classic  Kubernetes network proxy runs on each node.
convos           0.99.34     jhthorsen              -        Multiuser chat application that runs in your web browser
kube-proxy-eks   1.10.3      canonical-cloud-snaps  classic  Kubernetes network proxy runs on each node.
etcd             3.2.10      tvansteenburgh         -        Resilient key-value store by CoreOS
traefik-nacc     1.0.1       nacc                   -        Træfik, a modern reverse proxy
j2               0.3.1-0     cmars                  -        Command-line interface to Jinja2 for templating in shell scripts.
```

in this case not many, but I have found some cases where too many unrelevant results were returned, polluting the output and making hard to find what we are looking for. I guess this is what you are asking for.

So what you can do is filter the result with piping and grep, like this.

```
me@me-MyComputer:~$:~$ snap find docker | grep docker-inc
docker           18.06.1-ce  docker-inc             -        The docker app deployment mechanism
```

This time, as expected, only one result was returned.

The more detailed you can complete the content after the command grep  ("docker-inc" in this case), the better it will work. In this case I knew in advance the exact name of the publisher. That helps.